# How to solve InvalidRequestError encountered during execution of pandas.to_sql() using sqlalchemy connection?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to replace an existing table in MySQL database. I used the below piece of code to convert the data frame called `frame` to a database table:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.types import VARCHAR
database_username = 'root'
database_password = '1234'
database_ip       = 'localhost'
database_name     = 'my_new_database'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(database_username, database_password, database_ip, database_name),pool_size=3,pool_recycle=3600)
frame.to_sql(schema=database_name,con=database_connection,name='table1',if_exists='replace',chunksize=1000,dtype={'Enrollment No': VARCHAR(frame.index.get_level_values('Enrollment No').str.len().max())})
```

`table1` gets created successfully. But when I rerun the last line of the above code i.e. `frame.to_sql()`, it throws the below error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine(mysql+mysqlconnector://root:***@localhost/my_new_database) schema 'my_new_database': (table1)
```

I want to know why this error is thrown when the table already exists, even though I've used `if_exists='replace'` and why it works correctly only when creating the table for the first time. What must be done to avoid getting this error?

N.B.: Answers to similar questions only suggest using the table name in lowercase, which I'm following by naming the table as `'table1'`.

Comment: You have already specified the database name when you called `create_engine` so you don't need to supply it again in `to_sql`. MySQL does not deal with schemas in the conventional way (catalog.schema.object) so specifying `schema=` is not only redundant, it is probably confusing pandas/SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @GordThompson Actually I get the same error, whether `schema=`  is specified or not.

Comment: Can you try using mysqlclient or PyMySQL instead of MySQL-Connector to see if one of them works better? (MySQL-Connector is [not the preferred DBAPI layer for the MySQL dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector).)

Comment: Alright, thanks! i'll give it a a try